# how to get all outer(parent) divs id values from wrapper div using prototype?

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

I want to get only first outer all divs id value from below HTML  structure.

**I want to output like p1,test,contents which is outer divs
 ids value("p1,test,contents")** in "padder" div not all divs id value . i tried below code
 but it returns all div ids value but i want to **only** outer divs id
 and its value like **p1,test,contents**(this is outer divs id and its value which i want) in below html structure.

```
$('padder').select('div').each(function(el){
  alert($(el).id);
}); 

<div id="padder">
  <div id="p1">
    <div id="s1">
    </div><!-- Ends s1 div-->
  </div><!-- Ends p1 div-->
  <div id="test">
    <div class="subdiv">
    </div><!-- Ends subdiv div-->
  </div><!-- Ends test div-->
  <div id="contents">
    <div>
    </div><!-- Ends div-->
  </div><!-- Ends contents div-->  
</div><!-- Ends padder div-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the selector `#padder > div` to select all `div` elements that are a direct child of `#padder`.

Then just iterate through the elements, accessing the `id` using `el.id` [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/uy3zfb26/)

```
$$('#padder > div').each(function(el) {
    alert(el.id);
});
```

You can also map the `id`s to an array [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/jo6koLkj/) - (without prototype.js)

```
var ids = Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('#padder > div'), function (el, i) {
    return el.id;
});
```

Output:

```
["p1", "test", "contents"]
```